# Can't sum values from xml file in winforms

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, sum, integer

This is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int[] columnData = new int[dataGridView1.Rows.Count];
    columnData = (from DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows
                  where row.Cells[10].FormattedValue.ToString() != string.Empty
                  select Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[10].FormattedValue)).ToArray();
    textBoxSum.Text = columnData.Sum().ToString();
}
```

My xml file contains

```
<Invoice>
    <InvoiceNumber>UCBY87YZ-W6UBPZO0-30</InvoiceNumber>
    <TIN>101257639</TIN>
    <RequestedBy>UCBY87YZ</RequestedBy>
    <DateAndTimeOfPos/>
    <Cashier>14 Milena</Cashier>
    <PosInvoiceNumber>388/2.0</PosInvoiceNumber>
    <PaymentMethod/>
    <SDCTime_ServerTimeZone>21.04.2022. 18:59:33</SDCTime_ServerTimeZone>
    <InvoiceCounter>23/30ПП</InvoiceCounter>
    <SignedBy>W6UBPZO0</SignedBy>
    <TotalAmount>39150.0000</TotalAmount>
    <TransactionType>Sale</TransactionType>
    <InvoiceType>Normal</InvoiceType>
</Invoice>
```

This is only a small part of the xml file.

I'm able to sum TIN value probably because there are no decimals, but I cannot SUM the value of `TotalAmount` - I get an error:

> System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

I cannot change the XML file because I'm downloading it from some server every day

Comment: For floating point values, you have to replace `Convert.ToInt32` by e.g. `Convert.ToDecimal`. To be independent of your regional decimal separator setting, pass the invariant culture to the method.

Comment: Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal[]' to 'int[]'

Comment: Yes, you have to adapt the data type of columnData, too.

Comment: Thanx @KlausGütter !

Answer (score 0):

FOUND A WORKING SOLUTION :

```
decimal[] columnData = new decimal[dataGridView1.Rows.Count];
           columnData = (from DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows
                         where row.Cells[10].FormattedValue.ToString() != string.Empty
                         select Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[10].FormattedValue)).ToArray();
           textBoxSum.Text = columnData.Sum().ToString();
```